# Perf Result Conflict During Multiplexing

Tags: linux-kernel, performancecounter, perf, memory-access, intel-pmu

I have an `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4720HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz` (`Haswell`) processor (`Linux` `4.15.0-20-generic` kernel). In a relatively **idle** situation, I ran the following `Perf` commands and their outputs are shown, **below**. The counters are `offcore_response.all_data_rd.l3_miss.local_dram`, `offcore_response.all_code_rd.l3_miss.local_dram` and `mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss`:

```
sudo perf stat -a -e offcore_response.all_data_rd.l3_miss.local_dram,offcore_response.all_code_rd.l3_miss.local_dram,mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss
^C
 Performance counter stats for 'system wide':

           229,579      offcore_response.all_data_rd.l3_miss.local_dram                                     (99.72%)
           489,151      offcore_response.all_code_rd.l3_miss.local_dram                                     (99.77%)
           110,543      mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss                                     (99.79%)

       2.868899111 seconds time elapsed
```

As can be seen, event **multiplexing** occurred due to PMU **sharing** among these three events. In a **similar** scenario, I used the **same** command, except that I **appended** `:D` (mentioned in [The Linux perf Event Scheduling Algorithm](https://hadibrais.wordpress.com/2019/09/06/the-linux-perf-event-scheduling-algorithm/)) to **prevent** multiplexing for the **third** event:

```
sudo perf stat -a -e offcore_response.all_data_rd.l3_miss.local_dram,offcore_response.all_code_rd.l3_miss.local_dram,mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss:D
^C
 Performance counter stats for 'system wide':

           539,397      offcore_response.all_data_rd.l3_miss.local_dram                                     (68.71%)
           890,344      offcore_response.all_code_rd.l3_miss.local_dram                                     (68.67%)
           193,555      mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss:D                                   

       2.853095575 seconds time elapsed
```

But adding `:D` is leading to much **larger** values for all counters and this seems to occur **only** when event multiplexing occurs. Is this output **normal**? Are the percentage values in parentheses **valid**? How could the **differences** in counter values be **prevented**?

---

**UPDATE:**

I also traced the following **loop** implementation:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        for (unsigned long i = 0; i < 3 * 1e9; i++)
                ;

        return 0;
}
```

This time `Perf` was executed **7** (both **with** and **without** `:D`) but **not** using the `-a` option. The **commands** are as follows:

```
sudo perf stat -e offcore_response.all_data_rd.l3_miss.local_dram,offcore_response.all_code_rd.l3_miss.local_dram,mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss ./loop
```

and

```
sudo perf stat -e offcore_response.all_data_rd.l3_miss.local_dram,offcore_response.all_code_rd.l3_miss.local_dram,mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss:D ./loop
```

The values of the three counters are **compared** in the following figures:
[image]
[image]
[image]
For `all_data_rd`, the `:D` has almost **no** effect, for `all_code` **reduces** the values and for `load_uops_retired` causes **larger** values.

---

**UPDATE 2:**

Based on `Peter Cordes`'s comments, I used a **memory-intensive** program as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

#define DIM_SIZE 10000

using namespace std;

char from [DIM_SIZE][DIM_SIZE], to [DIM_SIZE][DIM_SIZE];

int main()
{
        for (char x = 'a'; x <= 'z'; x++)
        {
                // set the 100 million element char array 'from' 
to x
                for (int i = 0; i < DIM_SIZE; i++)
                        memset(from[i], x, DIM_SIZE);

                // copy the entire char array 'from' to char array 'to'
                for (int i = 0; i < DIM_SIZE; i++)
                        memcpy(to[i], from[i], DIM_SIZE);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

The following `Perf` commands and outputs show that the counter values are almost the **same**:

```
sudo perf stat -e offcore_response.all_data_rd.l3_miss.local_dram,offcore_response.all_code_rd.l3_miss.local_dram,mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss:D ./loop

 Performance counter stats for './loop':

        19,836,745      offcore_response.all_data_rd.l3_miss.local_dram                                     (50.04%)
            47,309      offcore_response.all_code_rd.l3_miss.local_dram                                     (49.96%)
         6,556,957      mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss:D                                   

       0.592795335 seconds time elapsed
```

and

```
    sudo perf stat -e offcore_response.all_data_rd.l3_miss.local_dram,offcore_response.all_code_rd.l3_miss.local_dram,mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss ./loop

 Performance counter stats for './loop':

        18,742,540      offcore_response.all_data_rd.l3_miss.local_dram                                     (66.64%)
            76,854      offcore_response.all_code_rd.l3_miss.local_dram                                     (66.64%)
         6,967,919      mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss                                     (66.72%)

       0.575828303 seconds time elapsed
```

Comment: Is this repeatable across runs?  Those aren't many counts. Different amount of idle background activity might be responsible for actually different things being measured.  Much better if you write a simple loop and measure it (without `-a`, if that works for off-core events) so you have a large fairly consistent number of those actual events taking place.

Comment: That loop you used won't create any extra memory traffic; it will either be purely registers, or if compiled without optimization will load/store the same one cache line so everything will hit in L1d cache.  So you still get a tiny amount of counts, probably just from interrupts which run some code that does miss in cache this this task is the `current` on that logical core (since you're not using `-a` this time).  A loop that does some memcpy or memset might make sense, or a simple known-good already written example is the STREAM benchmark.

Comment: Ok, well there you go, any difference was probably just "noise", and in your first two measurements noise is all you were measuring.  (Same for code-read counts in the 3rd test; glibc memset and memcpy are unrolled but not so big that they don't fit in the uop cache, let alone L1i cache.)  With the program having two different phases, different multiplexing timing will get different counts for `mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss`; extrapolating from one sample period won't always be correct.

Comment: You don't need `sudo` for `perf` if you set up your system to allow non-root to use PMU counters: `echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid`.  (Or `kernel.perf_event_paranoid = 0` in your sysctl.conf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your first two tests**, you're not doing anything to generate a consistent amount of off-core memory traffic, so **all you're measuring is the background "noise" on a mostly-idle system**.  (System-wide for the first test with `-a`, for the second just interrupt handlers which run some code that does miss in cache while this task is the `current` on a logical core.)

You never said anything about whether those differences are repeatable across runs, e.g. with `perf stat ... -r5` to re-run the same test 5 times, and print average and variance.  I'd expect it's not repeatable, just random fluctuation of background stuff like network and keyboard/mouse interrupts, but if the `:D` version makes a consistent or statistically significant difference that might be interesting.

---

In your 2nd test, the loop you used won't create any extra memory traffic; it will either be purely registers, or if compiled without optimization will load/store the same one cache line so everything will hit in L1d cache. So you still get a tiny amount of counts from it, mostly from the CRT startup and libc init code.  From your `main` itself, probably one code fetch and zero data loads that miss in L3 since stack memory was probably already hot in cache.

---

As I commented, a loop that does some memcpy or memset might make sense, or a simple known-good already written example is the STREAM benchmark, so that third test is finally something useful.

The code-read counts in the 3rd test are also just idle noise: glibc memset and memcpy are unrolled but small enough that they fit in the uop cache, so it doesn't even need to touch L1i cache.

**We do have an interesting difference in counts for `mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss` with / without `:D`,** and off-core data-reads L3 misses.
With the program having two different phases (memset and memcpy), different multiplexing timing will get sample different amounts of that loop. Extrapolating to the whole time from a few of those sample periods won't always be correct.

If `memset` uses NT stores (or `rep stosb` on a CPU [with ERMSB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43343231/enhanced-rep-movsb-for-memcpy)), it won't be doing any reads, just writes.  Those methods use a no-RFO store protocol to avoid fetching the old value of a cache line, because they're optimized for overwriting the full line.  Without that, plain stores could generate `offcore_response.all_data_rd.l3_miss.local_dram` I think, if RFO (Read For Ownership) count as part of all-data-read.  (On my Skylake, `perf list` has separate events for `offcore_response.demand_data_rd` vs. `offcore_response.demand_rfo`, but "all" would include both, and prefetches (non-"demand").)

`memcpy` has to read its source data, so it has a source of `mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss`.  It can also use NT stores or ERMSB to avoid load requests on the destination.

Glibc memcpy / memset *do* use NT stores or `rep movsb` / `rep stosb` for large-enough buffers.  So there will be a large difference in rate of `offcore_response.all_data_rd.l3_miss.local_dram` as well as `mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss` between the memcpy and memset portions of your workload.

(I wrote memcpy *or* memset when I was suggesting creating a simple consistent workload because that would make it uniform with time.  I hadn't looked carefully at what events you were counting, that it was only load uops and offcore load requests.  So `memset` wasn't a useful suggestion.)

And of course code reads that miss all the way to L3 are hard to generate.  In hand-written asm you could make a huge block of fully-unrolled instructions with [GAS](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Rept.html) `.rept 10000000` ; `lea %fs:0x1234(,%rax,4), %rcx` ; `.endr`.  Or with NASM `times 10000000 lea rcx, [fs: 0x1234 + rax*4]`.  (The segment prefix is just there to make it longer, no effect on the result.)  That's a long-ish instruction (7 bytes) with no false dependency that can run at least 2 per clock on modern Intel and AMD CPUs, so should go quickly through the CPUs legacy decoders, maybe fast enough to exceed prefetch and result in lots of demand-loads for code that miss in L3.

Comment: (I checked, and yes those 10M repeat counts to make about 90MB of code do result in counts for `offcore_response.demand_code_rd.any_response` on my Skylake client CPU.)

Comment: Regarding **repeatability**, for the **second** (*simple loop*) experiment, the chart *x-axis* represents **7** experiments (numbered from **0 through 6**). It seems **repeatable**. For the **first** (*whole-system*) experiment, also, it was **repeatable**.